# Android share screenshot with text on facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook, android-sharing

Hello friends i am facing problem with sharing functionality on facebook wall. I am sharing text and image, which is a captured screen of my application. But i unable to share text using following code. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/png");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "my awesome caption in the EXTRA_TITLE field");
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "your sharing text");
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pngUri); // Share
                                                                            // the
                                                                            // image
                                                                            // on
                                                                            // Facebook
        PackageManager pm = mActivity.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
        for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList)
        {
            if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains(sharingapp))
            {
                c++;
                final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
                final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
                shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                shareIntent.setComponent(name);
                startActivity(shareIntent);
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed?locale=en_GB

Comment: why don t you use FaceBookShareDialog? check Facebook SDK or here https://github.com/b099l3/FacebookImageShareIntent

Comment: Using the intent is fine, however Facebook will not let you set the message as that is against Platform Policies. The user MUST type in the message themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Intent to share in facebook you should try to use their WebDialog in sharing. Using Intent is not reliable all the time. (Sorry for my english :))

Here is my sample code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", name);
        params.putString("caption", caption);
        params.putString("description", desctription);
        params.putString("picture", image);

        WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(context, Session.getActiveSession(), params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                        if (error == null) {
                            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                            if (postId != null) {
                                ShareDialog.this.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Shared Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            // User clicked the "x" button
                            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Error posting story", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .build();
        feedDialog.show();
```